# Storyboard Animation for Path control not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, wpf-animation, coloranimation

So I have a Path object that is implemented as follows:

```
<Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M0,0L0.67,0 4,2.67 7.25,0 8,0 8,0.67 4,4 0,0.75z" Fill="Black" Height="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" Width="8">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

With this Path I have the following animation attached that works perfectly.

**WORKING:**

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStateGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="180" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

However when I add the color animations neither of the animations work. Also, the expand seems to happen instantaneously rather than expanding smoothly. The Collapse works fine though.

**NOT WORKING:**

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStateGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" />
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="180" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation To="Black" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" />
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arrow"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

It has to do with the coloranimation because when I try to perform the color animation by itself it doesn't work.
This is a part of the Telerik RadExpander user control.

If any other information is needed please don't hesitate to ask.

**NOTE 1:** 
If I set the Fill color in the path declaration to black and set the collapsed fill color to green the arrow will start out as green, but as soon as I expand it turns black and never changes color again.

**Note 2:** When the coloranimation is set the doubleanimation never works.

Comment: Out of curiosity and since I don't have time to tinker, but what happens if you replaced the words "Red" and "Black" with "#FFFF0000" and "#FF000000", would you get the same result?

Comment: @ChrisW. , I do get the same result. It may be worth noting that if I set the fill color in the actual path declaration to black and set the collapse visual state fill color to green then it sets the fill to green at the start (I'm assuming this is because it is defaulted to collapsed). However, when I expand and collapse it goes to the declaration color of black and never goes back to green.

Comment: Oh ya know what, I didn't realize you're doing this all on one object at first. If it were me I'd probably just copy the arrow, make one Red and One black with their transforms already applied and toggle their UIElement.Visibility instead. The way you have it, if you opened up the template in blend you should get a little warning notification icon thingy next to those states telling you something along the same concept.